# login hook for all pages

Tags: javascript, module, drupal-7

I have login button in all pages.I have created a custom module in drupal 7.'one_time_popup' is my module name.I have tried to add a js file after login.I have created a hook 'one_time_popup_user_login'.It works only for the home page I want to work it on other other page login also.now works only if I login on home page.If I login on other pages it doesn't add my js file

```
function one_time_popup_user_login($edit, $account){
if(user_is_logged_in){
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/service.js');
}
}
```

Comment: Not a drupal user. But is the js file being loaded in other pages?

Comment: file is not loaded in network

Comment: Well then. We found the root cause of your problem :)

Comment: even It doesn't shows any 404 error

Comment: Maybe there are two main template files - one for home and the other for app? and that the app template does not contain the js file included which is why it doesn't get loaded and so no error thrown

Comment: how to check it.I'm a newbie

Comment: Can't help you on that you'll have to check that yourself or ask your senior. Not a drupal user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151230/discussion-between-user3386779-and-sagar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with **hook_init**

```html
function modulename_init() {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'Modulename') . '/yourjs.js');
  }
}
```

include js in your custom module